# flutter layout question ，how to set the container width adaptive the content width

Tags: flutter

I  want the WebIconButton align top right, but get center in page,here is my code, I set the `MainAxisAlignment.end,`, but seems doesn't work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../colors.dart';
import 'webIconButton.dart';

class MTWebModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final dynamic content;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String buttonText;

  MTWebModal({
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
    required this.buttonText,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = [
      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
      Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
    ];

    if (content is List<Widget>) {
      children.addAll(content);
    } else if (content is Widget) {
      children.add(content);
    }

    children.addAll([
      SizedBox(height: 32.0),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: primary,
            ),
            child: Text(buttonText),
            onPressed: onPressed,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);

    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    WebIconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ]),
              ...children,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the redline box is what I want ,how to fix
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this code

```
    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
              IntrinsicWidth(
                child: Column(
                  children: children,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: the  row `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` I control   children's width not expanded and fit the content width, without the row , the width will fill the entire screen。I want the conetnt  adaptive content width, and the webIcon show the topRight

Comment: @liuestc i just updated my code, please check that